# Nestjs Swagger - introspectComments - How to pass @ApiTags, @ApiOperation and @ApiResponse responses in the comments?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

Nestjs Swagger - introspectComments - How to pass following options in plain comments?

- @ApiTags
- @ApiOperation - Especially the `operationId`
- @ApiResponse

```
@Controller()
export class MyController {

  @ApiTags('MyController')
  @ApiOperation({
    operationId: 'message'
    summary: 'Send Message',
    description: 'Using this endpoint you can pass in hello',
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Return Hello Message Response.',
    type: MessageResponseEntity,
  })
  @ApiBody({
    type: string,
  })
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() message: string): Promise<HelloEntity> {
    return await this.helloService.message(message);
  }
}
```